# PermissionError when installing sorl-thumbnail

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm using python3.4 / django1.6. when you try to install module sorl-thumbnail, get the following error message:

```
15:18 ~/drummersaransk $ pip3.4 install sorl-thumbnail==11.12.1b
Downloading/unpacking sorl-thumbnail==11.12.1b
Downloading sorl_thumbnail-11.12.1b-py33-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: sorl-thumbnail
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 671, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
pycompile=self.pycompile,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 215, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 205, in clobber
os.makedirs(destdir)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 237, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sorl'


Storing debug log for failure in /home/drummersaransk/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Try putting `sudo` at the start of the command.

Comment: its special hosting pythonanywhere.com. superuser privileges are not required

Comment: @dert: But if you accidentally did `sudo pip3.4 install sorl` when you shouldn't have, then `pip3.4 install sorl-thumbnail` probably _would_ get an exception just like this one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sudo` or run pip inside virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

If It is on your computer you must add **sudo** before the pip command like this:

```
sudo pip3.4 install sorl-thumbnail==11.12.1b
```

Comment: it is not on my computer. is not a special hosting. superuser privileges are not required
pythonanywhere.com

Answer (score -1):

sorry. I'm not paying attention. that's the right solution for hosting:

```
pip3.4 install sorl-thumbnail==11.12.1b
```

Comment: Is this a solution to your question, or a comment on another answer?